# Saving plot.ly image to RData file

Tags: r, plotly

I create a plot_ly image using:

```
MilesPlotly <- plot_ly(x = TripDetails$TotalDistanceMiles, type = "histogram")
```

I then want to save it to an RData file to simply open it later (hence pre-compute)

```
save(MilesPlotly, file = "my/path/here/myPlot.RData")
```

Later on I want to simply plot it by doing

```
load(my/path/here/myPlot.RData)
MilesPlotly
```

Now, this **works** on Mac. This does not work on my Ubuntu server on AWS.

Does anyone have any ideas why the discrepancy? The plotly version on both is 3.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work on my windows environment and `plotly_build()` solves it (I'm not sure this code works on your env).

```
MilesPlotly <- plot_ly(x = TripDetails$TotalDistanceMiles, type = "histogram")
MilesPlotly <- plotly_build(MilesPlotly)

save(MilesPlotly, file = "my/path/here/myPlot.RData")

load("my/path/here/myPlot.RData")
MilesPlotly
```

Answer (score 0):

After some tweaking, I realized I needed to do two things:

1) I updated R to 3.3.1

2) You need to "build" the plot before saving it. That means:

```
MilesPlotly <- plot_ly(x = TripDetails$TotalDistanceMiles, type = "histogram") %>% 
build()
```